# Doing both business and pleasure activities on a pure B1 visa

Tags: usa, b1-b2-visas

I applied for a B1/B2 US visa to take the Usmle step 2 CS exam. But I was only given a pure B1 visa. It really surprised me coz taking an exam doesn't really fit the description of a business purpose at least based from the B1 visa definitions I've read. Or does it? So my question is if I go to US on a pure B1 to take the exam? Can I also say I plan to visit some friends after the exam while I am already there? Is that allowed?

Comment: Not sure if this is a duplicate. Because if I was given a B1 visa to take the exam then this means they consider my taking of the exam a business purpose. So i'm not going without a business purpose. My question is if It's ok to tell the officer at the port of entry that I am also visiting friends after taking the exam..

Comment: @Mondz88 did you read the accepted answer to the duplicate question? I read: `You do not need to apply to change your nonimmigrant status if you were admitted into the United States for business reasons (B-1 visa category) and you wish to remain in the United States for pleasure before your authorized stay expires.`